# Помогите дописать программу)))

Tags: c++, visual-studio, строки, visual-c++

Нужно написать программу, которая записывает строки входного файла в исходный в обратном порядке (т.е. если есть строки "Привет, рад познакомится (ентер) Как дела?", то в исходном файле всё должно быть так: "?алед каК (ентер) ястимоканзоп дар ,тевирП"

Вот код, который написал я (он только переворачивает строки, но их порядок остается тем же):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    ifstream f("f.txt");
    ofstream g("g.txt");
    string s;
    while (getline(f, s))
    {
        reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        g << s << endl;
    }
    cout << "Рядки перевернуті!" << endl;
    g.close();
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```